# Surfacing data in ArcSDE enterprise geodatabases in Portal

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-portal

Is it possible to use data from ArcSDE geodatabases (hosted in Oracle, in this instance) in Portal webmaps? I've been searching documentation and the internet for a while, and it's implied that it's possible, but I can't seem to find a specific instance of it being done or how to do it.

Comment: Portal is just a front-end; you need an AGS map service based on the enterprise geodatabase source.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: The "publishing data on the web" classes span several days of instruction.  It's dirt easy, but too large for a comment field, and out of scope within GSE (likely to be closed as "too broad")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes (short answer)

How do I do that? (longer answer)

As @Vince and @Mike comment, the missing piece is "Publishing" a map and feature service(s) to ArcGIS for Server (AGS).  So the roadmap is:

1. a layer in ArcSDE (backend) gets modeled and populated with data, then
2. added to an MXD (desktop) and manipulated until it appears as desired, then
3. the Map is "Published" to an ArcGIS Server Map Service (middle-tier if you will) making multiple feature services (matching the MXD contents) available and ALSO referencing them within Portal (or ArcGIS Online), then
4. the Map services are managed within Portal Administrator (or AGS Online) to share them with the right groups, etc.
5. Applications are developed and deployed which consume these Map services and are based on web-language  prototype applications.

Each of these steps are documented to one degree or another, but the high-level roadmap isn't always clear when reading the detailed documentation.  Keep this roadmap handy while you [review this tutorial](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000003vt000000) (steps 3-4.)